# how to write if else statement inside DecorationImage() in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

while implementing an image picker in the flutter project.
1) when screen first load stored asset image should show
2) After clicking the image from image picker that image should replace the asset image

```
                Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                 child:Container(
                 width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*25,
                 height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*25,
                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal*20),
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: if(_image == null)     //before picking image load stored image
                    {
                      image:AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg')
                    }
                    else{
                        Image.file(_image),     //after clicking image picker load clicked image
                    }
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
               ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator like:

```
DecorationImage(
  image: _image == null ? AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg') : Image.file(_image),
)
```

Comment: Dart 2.12 version. Sound null safety and Dart FFI ship to the stable channel. Now it is not working. Please share any other solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh I'm not sure if your `_image` variable will ever be `null`, but if it is, then declare it using `File? _image`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In my case image is required but also handling exception, but still not working. My code is as: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green,image: DecorationImage(image: (userImageUrl.length > 0) ? (MasterFunctions().isValidUrl(userImageUrl)) ? CachedNetworkImageProvider(userImageUrl)  : AssetImage(userImageUrl)
 : AssetImage('assets/images/user_placeholder.png'),),),), Please share any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in your case with just if else you can use ternary operator

```
DecorationImage(
   image: _image == null ? AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg') : Image.file(_image),
   fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

In more complicated cases you need to extract internal method inside your method or make another private method

```
Widget makeWidget(){
   Image getImage(){
     if(_image == null) return AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg');
        return Image.file(_image);
     }

   return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child:Container(
                width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*25,
                height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*25,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal*20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                image: getImage()
                fit: BoxFit.fill))));
}
```

Comment: Dart 2.12 version. Sound null safety and Dart FFI ship to the stable channel. Now it is not working. Please share any other solution. Thanks.

Comment: can doing nested?

Answer (score 0):

it won't work

```
 image:DecorationImage(
    image: _image == null ? AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg') : Image.file(_image),
)
```

it should be

```
image: DecorationImage(
       image: _image == null ? AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg'): FileImage(_image),
```